# Strange claim about Allah (SWT)

Tags: islamic-basis

Salamo3alaykom, I recently put an eye on a video about Aqeedah uploaded by a channel run by Abu Mussab Wajdi Akkari, and I actually have not watched it entirely, but around 32:05 he says something like "Allah made Du'a against them, and Allah will reply". A question istantly popped up in my mind, how would Allah make Du'a in the first place? Now I'm not asking to watch the entire lecture but at least watch a surrounding snippet in order to extrapolate the context related to that, in my opinion, silly statement, because it is unconceivable to hear that Allah makes Du'a. It has most likely to be a slip of tongue, but I don't know.

The link: https://youtu.be/SSQduS1Vo9w

Answer (score 2):

This speaker's words (in English) in the snippet are not the most concise but he definitely is not saying that Allah supplicates. If we try to find faults in the words of speakers or eye their videos with suspicions, Satan will give us plenty to make issues out of when in reality those issues don't exist. Rather, Islam says to assume the best of others [and their words].

What he likely meant by "Allah made dua" is that Allah (ﷻ) is the One from whom the dua originates (source) and He taught us [Muslims] this dua against the wrongdoer to which He will then respond. In this case, Allah (ﷻ) says
  *( ۘ غُلَّتْ أَيْدِيهِمْ وَلُعِنُوا بِمَا قَالُوا)*
 ("Be their hands tied up and be they accursed for what they uttered")- Qur'an 5:64... in regards to the Jews.

Similarly, in verse 111:1 Allah said *(تَبَّتْ يَدَا أَبِي لَهَبٍ وَتَبَّ)* ("May the hands of Abu Lahab be ruined, and ruined is he."). Ibn Kathir in his tafsir says the first part of this is a supplication (dua). Obviously, it is a supplication for believers, and Allah (ﷻ) will respond to their saying it. Doesn't mean Allah (ﷻ) is supplicating.

The whole of Al Fatiha [first chapter of Qur'an] is itself a dua which Allah conveyed to teach us the best prayer of guidance. And when we [Muslims] recite it, Allah (ﷻ) responds to our reciting it. Again, Allah (ﷻ) is not supplicating.

The Qur'an is full of duas taught to us by Allah (ﷻ). Alhamdulillah.

Wa Alaikum As Salam WrWb